# How to pause a vba-excel macro and allow user interaction

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for a way to pause a macro and allow the user to manually input a "city" into a cell on the sheet, before resuming. I've found a number of different methods, but unfortunately my programming knowledge doesn't seem to be up to the task of implementing the suggestions. One method suggested using `GetTickCount` but I'm sure I'm missing something as I get an `Argument not Optional` message. Code is below, any advice or direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT: Have had a few responses suggesting different approaches but I don't have an understanding of why `GetTickCount` is failing. Any input on that? Thank you.

```
    Option Explicit
    Option Compare Text
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias "gettickcount64" (cytickcount As Currency) As LongPtr

    Sub AddPickups()
        Dim VendorList(100) As String, WeightList(100) As Double, PieceList(100) As Double, POList(100) As String, RKList(100) As Double, _
i As Integer, finished_button As Boolean, j As Integer, File_Path As _
String, CurrentDate As Date, DateString As String, SameVendorFlag As Boolean

    i = 1
    Range("a2").Select

    Do Until finished_button = True
        If SameVendorFlag = True Then
            VendorList(i) = VendorList(i - 1)
        Else
            VendorList(i) = InputBox("Please enter the name of the vendor.", "Add Vendor")
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 2).Value = VendorList(i)
        WeightList(i) = InputBox("Please enter the weight of the shipment.", "Add Weight")
        ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 0).Value = WeightList(i)
        PieceList(i) = InputBox("Please enter the number of pieces in the shipment.", "Add Pieces")
        ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 1).Value = PieceList(i)
        POList(i) = InputBox("Please enter the digits after ""SB000"" from the PO number of the shipment.", "Add PO #s")
        POList(i) = "SB000" & POList(i)
        ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 6).Value = POList(i)
        If MsgBox("Would you like to add another pickup?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            i = i + 1
            If MsgBox("Is it the same vendor?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                SameVendorFlag = True
            Else
                SameVendorFlag = False
            End If
        Else
            finished_button = True
            If MsgBox("Are any of the pickups outside of the City?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                MsgBox ("System will pause for 2 minutes so you can add the city information")
                Call WasteTime(120)
            End If
        End If
    Loop

    CurrentDate = Date
    DateString = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")

    Call Sort
    Call AssignRK(i)

    If MsgBox("Are you finished adding pickups?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        File_Path = "FilePath goes here"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File_Path & "FileName" & " - " _
            & DateString & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    End Sub

    Sub AssignRK(i)
    Dim LastRK As Double, FirstRK As Double, j As Integer

    LastRK = InputBox("Please enter the highest RK number PREVIOUSLY USED", "RK Number")
    FirstRK = LastRK + 1
    Range("f2").Select
    For j = 1 To i
        If j = 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 0).Value = FirstRK
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(j - 1, 0).Value = FirstRK + (j - 1)
        End If
    Next j
    End Sub

    Sub Sort()
    Range("RegionTag").CurrentRegion.Select
    Range("RegionTag").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("CitySort"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, key2:=Range("VendorSort"),        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, key3:=Range("POSort"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End Sub

    Sub WasteTime(Finish As Long)

    Dim NowTick As Long
    Dim EndTick As Long

    EndTick = getTickCount + (Finish * 1000)

    Do
        NowTick = getTickCount
        DoEvents
        Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick
    End Sub
```

Comment: How about prompting a textbox in which data needs to be entered. You can then programmatically transfer the data to the cell after completion.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had hesitated to do that because I don't want it to have to prompt for every entry since most will not have a city tag. Is there a way to have it prompt for the city info at the end and match it to the correct entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to find a solution involving a `modeless userform` that worked well to pause the execution until the userform command button is clicked. The remaining code executes in the button click sub. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution please? It would be great to replicate something like this on a project I'm working on!

Answer (score 3):

You can grab a city name by doing the below:

```
If MsgBox("Are any of the pickups outside of the City?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Dim City as String
    City = InputBox("Provide City Name")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10") = City
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had hesitated to do that because I don't want it to have to prompt for every entry since most will not have a city tag. Is there a way to have it prompt for the city info at the end and match it to the correct entry?

Comment: IMO - it would be better to not prompt at all and have the user enter any extra cities before running the code and then have the code check for extra cities and process as needed. My approach is to get as much info as possible up front so that once the procedure is executed the user does not have to interact anymore. I feel it's bad user experience to have to wait for prompts.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I feel like that means pre-sorting and pre-entering a bunch of the information. The goal was to automate the process as much as possible and try to speed it up a bit. 90% of the entries default to leaving the "City" cell blank and a few others will need tags like "PA", "WAR", "OOT".

Comment: *Is there a way to have it prompt for the city info at the end* - Sure. You can can move this code block to be wherever you want it.

Comment: Thanks Scott, how would I then make sure that the "city" tag gets applied to the correct entry?

Comment: that's up to to determine given your code. no way for me to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the user interacts with your code, have you tried with InputBox?

```
myValue = InputBox("Give me some input", "Hi", 1)
```

> You can see example in:
>   http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/inputbox-function.html

InputBox event automatically pauses your code execution until the user input some data. **Don't forget to validate the data entered by the user.**

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had hesitated to do that because I don't want it to have to prompt for every entry since most will not have a city tag. Is there a way to have it prompt for the city info at the end and match it to the correct entry?

Comment: You can prompt only if your script validates the data and confirm that you need information, for example, Cell Value = "" or if the value is not one you expected.

Comment: I feel like the challenge with that approach is that most of them are left blank by default and only a few of the entries will require a "City" tag. some examples of "City" tags are, "PA", "WAR", "OOT".

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how a userform will allow me to pause the execution and allow the user to manually input the specific city information for the necessary entries? Thank you!